# Bittrix при отправке формы не заполняет одно из полей результата

Tags: php, веб-программирование, битрикс

Есть выплывающая форма, которая вроде и работает и отправляет данные и они записываться в результат. Но одно ни как не хочет.
Аякс постоянно возврощает что поле мол не заполнено.
Код шаблона и аякс запросса https://yadi.sk/d/oOJdAI09ieQQ9
Скажите хоть в какой строчке ошибка

Comment: Из шаблона не видно, что у вас там за форма и какие поля в ней. В вопросе вы не указали какое именно поле не проходит.

Comment: Поля всего 3:
Имя
Емейл
Текст
Не приходит именно емейл

Comment: Вы в php коде проверяли, что приходит на сервер? Я так понимаю вы берете данные из массива $_REQUEST. Выведите массив на экран командой `var_dump($_REQUEST);` или `print_r($_REQUEST);`

Comment: Там идёт проверка на поля, я для теста поставил все 3 поля обязательными. Два поля отправляются и ошибок php невозврощает, а с емейлом всегда кидает ошибку.

Comment: Прочитайте мой комментарий выше еще раз.

Comment: Реквест говорит, что всё что нужно дошло

Comment: Раз данные пришли, проблема не в ajax, а в проверках на стороне сервера.